# How to use HidD_GetHidGuid() in c++?

Tags: c++, guid, hid

I've posted a similar topic/question, but this time it's a bit different.

I'm just trying to use the HidD_GetHidGuid() function to get the window's guid for some hid devices, but it's giving me a error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _HidD_GetHidGuid@4 referenced in function _main

Heres my code:

```
//mainframe.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
#include<hidsdi.h>
#include<SetupAPI.h>
}

int main()
{
    int iQuit;
    LPGUID guid;
    HidD_GetHidGuid(guid);

    std::cout << "testing program" << std::endl;
    std::cout << guid << std::endl;


    std::cin >> iQuit;

    return 0;
}
```

In my VC++ directories I've added C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\ddk and C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\inc\api to the "include directories". For "Library directories", I have added C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib

But it's just giving this 1 error, have no idea why... Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538924%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to link against `hid.lib`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, but I thought adding the C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib path will do it?? May I ask you how do you link the hid.lib? I tried doing it (in VS 2010) through properties >> Linker >> Input >> additional Dependencies. But still not working... just saying cannot open file :S

Comment: Sorry, nvm. Missed type the path :P. Thanks again :)

Comment: You need to add it here: http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/images/vc8_libs.gif

Comment: even then it dint work for me. I had to include the following   
    `extern "C"
    {
    #include <hidsdi.h>
    }`

Comment: @MaxwellWeru Good call.  The C++ name mangling was causing my linking errors as well.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your header

## pragma comment (lib, "hid.lib")

Comment: add more description to your answer , including how does it solves the problem :)

Comment: Its basically just a a way to include the link to hid library from within source code rather than doing it from properties in visual studio .