# How to find device using GUID in C++

Tags: c++, device, guid, hid

this is a 2 part question.

Firstly of all, here's my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

extern "C"
{
#include<hidsdi.h>
#include<SetupAPI.h>
}

int main()
{
    int iQuit;
    GUID guid;

    HidD_GetHidGuid(&guid);
    //SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, 

    std::cout << "testing program" << std::endl;
    std::cout << guid.Data1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << guid.Data2 << std::endl;
    std::cout << guid.Data3 << std::endl;
    std::cout << guid.Data4 << std::endl;

    std::cin >> iQuit;

    return 0;
}
```

The result is are printed out:

```
1293833650
61807
4559
//Data4 prints out e pie for some reason.
```

So my first question is, is there a way to check what the guid that I've got here belongs to which device? I've looked at the device manager section and I can't seem to find it.

My second question is how do I loop through all of the devices and store all the guid on the computer?

Any advice and help will be greatly appreciated. And sorry for the long message

Thanks

Comment: GUIDs are used for each and everything. It is not necessary that a specific GUID belongs to any device at all.



The enumeration of devices depend on the device type. Which device type do you want to attach?

Comment: The odds you'll get an answer are the inverse quadratic of the number of questions you ask.  Try to ask just one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HidD_GetHidGuid() in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485643/how-to-use-hidd-gethidguid-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `HidD_GetHidGuid` returns the GUID for all HID class devices, not the GUID of a single device.

To enumerate all the devices take a look at [SetupDiGetClassDevs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Example 5.